# Are recommendation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to buy a chromatic harmonica, never had one before and this topic hasn't been discussed on the web. Furthermore, harmonica forums are either dead or so inactive, therefore chances of getting multiple reviews are low.

May I ask this question on this site: "What are the best chromatic harmonicas out there for chromatic beginners?" Or will it be closed? I want to hear real opinions from experts and know the pros and cons and recommendations.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic but, as Dom says, generally applicable advice questions are not.  We want to give you the tools to investigate and assess your options, rather than talking about specific products.

Answer (score 7):

"Best" typically comes with a lot of opinion and personal preferences especially when it comes to instruments and equipment and questions that ask for specific recommendations are closed as primarily opinion based, but  you can ask about and it is encouraged to ask *what to look for* in an instrument or piece of equipment.

The difference is slight, but it gives you an answer that is not tied to specific product but instead features in products that can be applied to any chromatic harmonica you look at or consider getting.

So instead I suggest asking :

#### As a beginner, what should I look for in a chromatic harmonica?

Comment: ok, and i mean best as in good, not necessarily the "best", the thing is they don't sell harmonicas in my country, all chinese and only diatonic, so i have to get it from amazon, and perhaps wait 2 month for it and pay fees for shipping and so on, therefore i have to make sure I'm buying quality

Answer (score 2):

The real problem with recommendations is that they are always subjective and always difficult to verify. Every post on SE -- and especially an answer -- should be *objective* and, to some extent, *verifiable*.

What you can do and is, in my opinion, completely fine, is to come to the [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) and discuss it there. The chat room isn't extremely active, but there are couple people spending their time there, so you have a chance someone will be willing to help you. But keep in mind that it is only these people's opinions! Also, remember that someone cluttering the chat with lots of questions can become annoying (been there done that a few times, I'm afraid...).

Answer (score 0):

You elude to the problem with such a question in your post * I want to hear real **opinions** from experts and know the pros and cons and recommendations.*

Questions that are solely based on opinions just simply do not fit this site. This has greatly to do with the type of website this site is.

In a broader sense the internet fills two basic roles. It educates and it entertains. This site has almost solely to do with educating people through questions and answers to a plethora of topics.

When you ask a question that garners opinion that is not based on facts then it really takes away the chance of educating people in any meaningful manner.

In your example you may get 10 answer saying completely different things that is solely based on harmonica players opinions. The question you have to ask yourself then is how does these ten different answers educate you in any meaningful manner?

Those ten answers may all be equally valid opinions. How would we decide on the quality of these opinions? and what purpose would such answers fill? The answer is not anything meaningful.

This site is a great education tool. So when posts on this site do not educate people not only is it off topic but it also threatens the viability of this website. This has a lot to do with why the community's guidelines are enforced at times harshly.

Comment: This is exactly what I think is wrong with this site.  Everything we post here is an opinion and as long as they are not offensive, they should be allowed.